# What is the correct way to install (tar.xz) package on CentOs 7

Tags: centos

Take a look at [all openconnect versions](ftp://ftp.infradead.org/pub/ocserv/).
Now i want to install `ocserv-0.12.3.tar.xz` on CentOS 7 machine.

For install (tar.xz) package i did these commands, but nothing installed :

```
sudo yum remove ocserv
wget ftp://ftp.infradead.org/pub/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3.tar.xz
mkdir /usr/local/ocserv
tar xvf ocserv-0.12.3.tar.xz -C /usr/local/ocserv
cd /usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3
sudo ./configure && make && make check
sudo make install
```

What did i do wrong?
What is the correct way to install (tar.xz) package on CentOs 7?

---

**EDIT :**
Here is the result after my commands :

```
[root@Hamoon ocserv-0.12.3]# sudo ./configure
```

`To many yes during ./configure`

---

```
 [root@Hamoon ocserv-0.12.3]# sudo make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3'
Making all in gl
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/gl'
  GEN      arg-nonnull.h
  GEN      c++defs.h
  GEN      warn-on-use.h
  GEN      stddef.h
  GEN      stdio.h
  GEN      stdlib.h
  GEN      string.h
  GEN      strings.h
  GEN      sys/stat.h
  GEN      sys/time.h
  GEN      sys/types.h
  GEN      time.h
  GEN      unistd.h
make  all-recursive
make[3]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/gl'
make[4]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/gl'
  CC       c-ctype.o
  CC       c-strcasecmp.o
  CC       c-strncasecmp.o
  CC       unistd.o
  CC       strcasestr.o
  AR       libgnu.a
make[4]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/gl'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/gl'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/gl'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/src'
make  all-am
make[3]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/src'
  CC       occtl/occtl-occtl.o
  CC       occtl/occtl-pager.o
  CC       occtl/occtl-time.o
  CC       occtl/occtl-cache.o
  CC       occtl/occtl-ip-cache.o
  CC       occtl/occtl-nl.o
  CC       occtl/occtl-print.o
  CC       occtl/occtl-json.o
  CC       occtl/occtl-hex.o
  CC       occtl/occtl-unix.o
  CC       occtl/occtl-geoip.o
  CC       occtl/occtl-session-cache.o
  CC       common/libcommon_a-common.o
  CC       common/libcommon_a-system.o
  CC       common/libcommon_a-cloexec.o
  CC       common/libcommon_a-base64-helper.o
  AR       libcommon.a
  CC       protobuf/protobuf-c/libprotobuf_a-protobuf-c.o
  AR       libprotobuf.a
  CC       ccan/hash/libccan_a-hash.o
  CC       ccan/htable/libccan_a-htable.o
  CC       ccan/list/libccan_a-list.o
  CC       ccan/talloc/libccan_a-talloc.o
  AR       libccan.a
  CC       ctl.pb-c.o
  CC       ipc.pb-c.o
  AR       libipc.a
  CCLD     occtl/occtl
  CC       ocpasswd/ocpasswd-ocpasswd.o
  CCLD     ocpasswd/ocpasswd
  CC       main.o
  CC       main-auth.o
  CC       worker-vpn.o
  CC       worker-auth.o
  CC       tlslib.o
  CC       main-worker-cmd.o
  CC       ip-lease.o
  CC       main-proc.o
  CC       log.o
  CC       tun.o
  CC       config-kkdcp.o
  CC       config.o
  CC       worker-resume.o
  CC       sec-mod-resume.o
  CC       worker-http-handlers.o
  CC       html.o
  CC       worker-http.o
  CC       main-user.o
  CC       worker-misc.o
  CC       route-add.o
  CC       worker-privs.o
  CC       sec-mod.o
  CC       sec-mod-db.o
  CC       sec-mod-auth.o
  CC       auth/pam.o
  CC       auth/plain.o
  CC       auth/radius.o
  CC       auth/common.o
  CC       auth/gssapi.o
  CC       auth-unix.o
  CC       acct/radius.o
  CC       acct/pam.o
  CC       icmp-ping.o
  CC       worker-kkdcp.o
  CC       subconfig.o
  CC       sec-mod-sup-config.o
  CC       sup-config/file.o
  CC       main-sec-mod-cmd.o
  CC       sup-config/radius.o
  CC       worker-bandwidth.o
  CC       vasprintf.o
  CC       worker-proxyproto.o
  CC       config-ports.o
  CC       proc-search.o
  CC       ip-util.o
  CC       main-ban.o
  CC       valid-hostname.o
  CC       str.o
  CC       http-parser/http_parser.o
  CC       setproctitle.o
  CC       sec-mod-cookies.o
  CC       inih/ini.o
  CC       lzs.o
  CC       kkdcp_asn1_tab.o
  CC       main-ctl-unix.o
  CC       pcl/libpcl_a-pcl.o
pcl/pcl.c: In function ‘co_create’:
pcl/pcl.c:385:17: warning: unused variable ‘r’ [-Wunused-variable]
  int alloc = 0, r = CO_STK_COROSIZE;
                 ^
pcl/pcl.c: At top level:
pcl/pcl.c:62:12: warning: ‘co_ctx_stackdir’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int co_ctx_stackdir(void)
            ^
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-stringop-truncation" [enabled by default]
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-implicit-fallthrough" [enabled by default]
  CC       pcl/libpcl_a-pcl_version.o
  CC       pcl/libpcl_a-pcl_private.o
  AR       libpcl.a
  CCLD     ocserv
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/src'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/src'
Making all in doc
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/doc'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/doc'
Making all in tests
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/tests'
Making all in docker-ocserv
make[3]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/tests/docker-ocserv'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/tests/docker-ocserv'
Making all in docker-kerberos
make[3]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/tests/docker-kerberos'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/tests/docker-kerberos'
make[3]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/tests'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/tests'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/tests'
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3'
```

---

```
[root@Hamoon ocserv-0.12.3]# sudo make check
Making check in gl
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/gl'
make  check-recursive
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/gl'
make[3]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/gl'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `check-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/gl'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/gl'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/gl'
Making check in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/src'
make  check-am
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/src'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `check-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/src'
Making check in doc
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/doc'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `check'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/doc'
Making check in tests
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/tests'
Making check in docker-ocserv
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/tests/docker-ocserv'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `check'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/tests/docker-ocserv'
Making check in docker-kerberos
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/tests/docker-kerberos'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `check'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/tests/docker-kerberos'
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/tests'
make  str-test str-test2 ipv4-prefix ipv6-prefix kkdcp-parsing json-escape ban-ips port-parsing human_addr valid-hostname url-escape html-escape cstp-recv proxyproto-v1 \
  ocpasswd-test  radius-test unix-test kerberos-test radius-test-config proxyproto-test proxyproto-v1-test proxyproto-unix-test reload-info-test radius-group-test test-iroute test-multi-cookie test-pass-script test-cookie-timeout test-cookie-timeout-2 test-explicit-ip test-cookie-invalidation test-user-config test-append-routes test-ban multiple-routes haproxy-connect traffic lz4-compression lzs-compression aes256-cipher aes128-cipher oc-aes256-gcm-cipher oc-aes128-gcm-cipher test-config-per-group ac-aes128-gcm-cipher ac-aes256-gcm-cipher no-dtls-cipher
make[3]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/tests'
  CC       str-test.o
  CCLD     str-test
  CC       str-test2.o
  CCLD     str-test2
  CC       ipv4-prefix.o
  CCLD     ipv4-prefix
  CC       ipv6-prefix.o
  CCLD     ipv6-prefix
  CC       kkdcp-parsing.o
  CCLD     kkdcp-parsing
  CC       json-escape.o
  CCLD     json-escape
  CC       ban_ips-ban-ips.o
In file included from ban-ips.c:31:0:
../src/main-ban.c: In function ‘check_if_banned’:
../src/main-ban.c:251:7: warning: unused variable ‘txt’ [-Wunused-variable]
  char txt[MAX_IP_STR];
       ^
ban-ips.c: At top level:
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-stringop-truncation" [enabled by default]
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-implicit-fallthrough" [enabled by default]
  CCLD     ban-ips
  CC       port-parsing.o
  CCLD     port-parsing
  CC       human_addr-human_addr.o
  CCLD     human_addr
  CC       valid-hostname.o
  CCLD     valid-hostname
  CC       url-escape.o
  CCLD     url-escape
  CC       html-escape.o
  CCLD     html-escape
  CC       cstp_recv-cstp-recv.o
In file included from cstp-recv.c:37:0:
../src/tlslib.c: In function ‘tls_audit_log_func’:
../src/tlslib.c:431:14: warning: variable ‘ws’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  worker_st * ws;
              ^
../src/tlslib.c: In function ‘certificate_check’:
../src/tlslib.c:568:14: warning: variable ‘cert_name’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  const char *cert_name = "unnamed";
              ^
cstp-recv.c: At top level:
../src/tlslib.c:54:13: warning: ‘tls_reload_ocsp’ declared ‘static’ but never defined [-Wunused-function]
 static void tls_reload_ocsp(main_server_st* s, struct vhost_cfg_st *vhost);
             ^
../src/tlslib.c:424:13: warning: ‘tls_log_func’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static void tls_log_func(int level, const char *str)
             ^
../src/tlslib.c:442:12: warning: ‘verify_certificate_cb’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int verify_certificate_cb(gnutls_session_t session)
            ^
../src/tlslib.c:561:13: warning: ‘certificate_check’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static void certificate_check(main_server_st *s, const char *vhostname, gnutls_pcert_st *pcert)
             ^
../src/tlslib.c:625:13: warning: ‘set_dh_params’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static void set_dh_params(main_server_st* s, struct vhost_cfg_st *vhost)
             ^
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-stringop-truncation" [enabled by default]
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-implicit-fallthrough" [enabled by default]
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-stringop-truncation" [enabled by default]
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-implicit-fallthrough" [enabled by default]
  CCLD     cstp-recv
  CC       proxyproto-v1.o
  CCLD     proxyproto-v1
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `ocpasswd-test'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `radius-test'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `unix-test'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `kerberos-test'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `radius-test-config'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `proxyproto-test'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `proxyproto-v1-test'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `proxyproto-unix-test'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `reload-info-test'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `radius-group-test'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `test-iroute'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `test-multi-cookie'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `test-pass-script'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `test-cookie-timeout'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `test-cookie-timeout-2'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `test-explicit-ip'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `test-cookie-invalidation'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `test-user-config'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `test-append-routes'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `test-ban'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `multiple-routes'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `haproxy-connect'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `traffic'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `lz4-compression'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `lzs-compression'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `aes256-cipher'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `aes128-cipher'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `oc-aes256-gcm-cipher'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `oc-aes128-gcm-cipher'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `test-config-per-group'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `ac-aes128-gcm-cipher'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `ac-aes256-gcm-cipher'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `no-dtls-cipher'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/tests'
make  check-TESTS
make[3]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/tests'
make[4]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/tests'
PASS: ocpasswd-test
SKIP: radius-test
SKIP: unix-test
SKIP: kerberos-test
SKIP: radius-test-config
SKIP: proxyproto-test
SKIP: proxyproto-v1-test
SKIP: proxyproto-unix-test
SKIP: reload-info-test
SKIP: radius-group-test
SKIP: test-iroute
SKIP: test-multi-cookie
SKIP: test-pass-script
SKIP: test-cookie-timeout
SKIP: test-cookie-timeout-2
SKIP: test-explicit-ip
SKIP: test-cookie-invalidation
SKIP: test-user-config
SKIP: test-append-routes
SKIP: test-ban
SKIP: multiple-routes
SKIP: haproxy-connect
SKIP: traffic
SKIP: lz4-compression
SKIP: lzs-compression
SKIP: aes256-cipher
SKIP: aes128-cipher
SKIP: oc-aes256-gcm-cipher
SKIP: oc-aes128-gcm-cipher
SKIP: test-config-per-group
SKIP: ac-aes128-gcm-cipher
SKIP: ac-aes256-gcm-cipher
SKIP: no-dtls-cipher
PASS: str-test
PASS: str-test2
PASS: ipv4-prefix
PASS: ipv6-prefix
PASS: kkdcp-parsing
PASS: json-escape
PASS: ban-ips
PASS: port-parsing
PASS: human_addr
PASS: valid-hostname
PASS: url-escape
PASS: html-escape
PASS: cstp-recv
PASS: proxyproto-v1
============================================================================
Testsuite summary for ocserv 0.12.3
============================================================================
# TOTAL: 47
# PASS:  15
# SKIP:  32
# XFAIL: 0
# FAIL:  0
# XPASS: 0
# ERROR: 0
============================================================================
make[4]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/tests'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/tests'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/tests'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/tests'
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3'
```

---

```
[root@Hamoon ocserv-0.12.3]# sudo make install
Making install in gl
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/gl'
make  install-recursive
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/gl'
make[3]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/gl'
make[4]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/gl'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/gl'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/gl'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/gl'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/gl'
Making install in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/src'
make  install-am
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/src'
make[3]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/src'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/bin'
  /bin/install -c occtl/occtl ocpasswd/ocpasswd '/usr/local/bin'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/bin'
 /bin/install -c ocserv-fw '/usr/local/bin'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/sbin'
  /bin/install -c ocserv '/usr/local/sbin'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/src'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/src'
Making install in doc
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/doc'
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/doc'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/man/man8'
 /bin/install -c -m 644 ocserv.8 ocpasswd.8 occtl.8 '/usr/local/share/man/man8'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/doc'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/doc'
Making install in tests
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/tests'
Making install in docker-ocserv
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/tests/docker-ocserv'
make[3]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/tests/docker-ocserv'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/tests/docker-ocserv'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/tests/docker-ocserv'
Making install in docker-kerberos
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/tests/docker-kerberos'
make[3]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/tests/docker-kerberos'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/tests/docker-kerberos'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/tests/docker-kerberos'
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/tests'
make[3]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/tests'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/tests'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/tests'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3/tests'
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3'
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3'
```

Comment: What kind of errors you get when you execute the commands?

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: Side note: it is not good practice for end users to untar tarballs in `/usr/something` and invoke `sudo ./configure`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The software was installed:

```
/bin/install -c occtl/occtl ocpasswd/ocpasswd '/usr/local/bin'
/bin/install -c ocserv-fw '/usr/local/bin'
/bin/install -c ocserv '/usr/local/sbin'
```

You’ll find `occtl`, `ocpasswd` and `ocserv-fw` in `/usr/local/bin`, and `ocserv` in `/usr/local/sbin`.

Comment: But why this command tells nothing installed : `sudo yum info ocserv` ?

Comment: It shows version 0.12.2 instead of version 0.12.3 / Also this command does not work : `sudo systemctl status ocserv` and tells `Unit ocserv.service could not be found`.

Comment: @SilverLight, you wont see it as `rpm` package because you install it from source. Same is true about `ocserv.service`. When you install from source usually you do not have such goodies. Better install it from rpm as discussed in other Q/A